# What is PECL uploadprogress extensions support for multiple files?

Tags: iframe, file-upload, pecl

I created a script in HTML5 to handle multiple files uploads using XHR's progress event; but since IE is so behind on the HTML5 front and I need to upload files cross domain I'm recoding my script to use the old fashion iframe submit way.

I installed the PECL uploadprogress extension as a replacement to handle getting the upload progress, but my question is how does it work with uploading multiple files at a time?

I know you pass an identifier with your post to be able to retrieve the upload status but does that work only on a form with a single file or will it work with multiple files through the same post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question.  The uploadprogress PECL extension does support multiple files.  The identifier you pass to your form will keep track of the upload status for all files you post to a page.

So you don't need to break your files down to individual posts.